# GSON is converting string to number in Json serialization

Tags: android, json, gson

GSON is converting a string that contains a number into a number in Json. I'm using the following code to generate a JsonElement:

```
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement sendPayload = parser.parse("{post_data : {login: "+login+", password: "+password+"}}");
    Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "Login Send payload: " + sendPayload);
```

It prints:

```
    LoginServiceManager﹕ Login Send payload: {"post_data":{"login":"teste@oferr.me","password":123456}}
```

It should print:

```
    LoginServiceManager﹕ Login Send payload: {"post_data":{"login":"teste@oferr.me","password":"123456"}}
```

How to achieve that?

Comment: What is the type of `password`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the bug is in your code that constructs a JSON string and passes this to `parser.parse()`:

```
"{post_data : {login: teste@oferr.me, password: 123456}}"
```

That's not valid JSON so you're lucky or unlucky (depending on viewpoint) that `parse()` doesn't throw an exception.

A quick fix would be:

```
JsonElement sendPayload = parser.parse(
  "{\"post_data\": {\"login\": \"" + login + "\", \"password\": \"" + password + "\"}}");
```

A more robust fix would be to construct a JsonElement using its API. E.g. that wouldn't break if the password string contains `"`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey You can try following workaround:

```
JsonElement sendPayload = parser.parse("{post_data : {login: "+login+", password:\""+password+"\"}}");
```